# Python does not work but gives no error message

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I am new to programming/scripting in general and just becoming to understand the basics of the workings of python. Anyways, I have here a script I have been working on to randomly  find a keyword in a column containing text of excel file and print 'word word keyword word word' in another column. Here the words are present in the text given.

```
import openpyxl

path5 = "C:\\Users\\AC48330\\Desktop\\my files\\FINAL.xlsx"
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(path5)
Sheet = wb['Sheet']
y = "you"
for i, cellObj in enumerate(Sheet['AW'], 1):
    line = Sheet['AW']
    words = str(line).split()
if y in words:
    index = words.index(y)
    before = index - min(index, 2)
    after = index + min(len(words) - 1 - index, 2) + 1
    print((words[before:after]), Sheet['BB'])

wb.save('finale.xlsx')
```

Please excuse if this seems like a stupid question but I am new to this after all :(. When I run the above script I receive no output as well as no error message resulting in me not knowing what I am doing wrong!

Comment: In your `for i, cellObj in #...` line you are not referencing `line` variable for the next line, so it'll throw an exception. i.e. You were using `line` from nowhere.

Comment: use the step debugger to trace code execution (https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html)

Comment: Your `for` loop doesn't print anything. After it finishes, the `if y in words:` is evaluated and if it's false nothing is printed. I think your indentation is wrong. Try indenting the `if` statement and the next 4 lines following all one more indentation level.

Comment: i tried indenting , it still doesnt work

Comment: Then `y` is never in `words`, so the 4 indented lines beneath the `if` statement are never executed. This leads me to suspect that the `words = str(line).split()` might not be doing what you expect, so you'll have to debug that.

Comment: `line` is an iterator of cell objects in the column `AW` which is why searching it for text is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

It is quite strange that you use `enumerate` on a sheet column, and then discard the results from the loop.

To properly get the value of each cell:

```
for i, cellObj in enumerate(Sheet['AW'], 1):
    words = cellObj.value
    print (words)
```

Then you can go ahead and do your `if y in words` check for each individual cell.

If what you really want is to obtain a list of all the cell values in column `AW`, use a list comprehension instead:

```
words = [cellObj.value for cellObj in Sheet["AW"]]
print (words)
```